# Fail Gradle TaskAction when .execute() command fails

Tags: error-handling, gradle

How should you retrieve output and errors during ".execute()" operations and fail the task if there are errors? Are errors automatically handled for project.copy {...} and similar tasks? Is there any equivalent to project.sync {...} or project.exec {...} that can be used?

```
class SomeTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def translate() {
        def execCommand = "<SOME_COMMAND>"
        println 'Command\n' + execCommand
        println execCommand.execute().text
    }
}
```

When running the task, it spews out a number of errors and then marks it as successful. The code should instead detect when the execute() command has failed and fail the whole task.

```
Translated 6 files: 301 errors, 0 warnings

:base:someTask (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 3.387 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I'm also using the following to log STDOUT to the info logs for easy access (so you just add -I to see the logs). Are there any recommended alternatives to this?

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.INFO
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`project.exec {...}` can be used to execute shell scripts. It is configured in the same way as [Exec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html). Note how each argument needs to be split up in to individual values before passing it to the `args` method.

```
class SomeTask extends DefaultTask {

    def otherFlags = "-n -E"

    @TaskAction
    def translate() {
        project.exec {
            executable "echo"
            args "-e"
            args otherFlags.split()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Groovy's `String#execute`, it's typically better to use Gradle's `project.exec {}` (which is configured in the exact same way as an `Exec` task and allows to reroute standard out/err), which by default will throw an exception if the command returns a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Peter, thanks and please comment / edit on the answer I've written below.

Comment: I'd say my post answers your question just fine.